# How to reproduce this shot of a person with reflections in front of them?

Tags: portrait, reverse-engineering

[Renuka Puri: Portrait of Prime Minister Narendra Modi and reflection of crowd in the glass after the parliamentary party meeting](https://www.instagram.com/p/Bl_ICgfDois)

How can I reproduce this shot, especially the reflections in front of the person?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This shouldn't be too hard. The photo was shoot through a pane of glass. The glass is at a slight angle, reflecting the crowd.

Here is an example of how to do this:

```
                  000000  <-  Crowd
       Glass   
          \   
Subject    \             <- [} 0 You pointing your camera at the subject
            \                 \|
```

This way the crowd is shown on the glass along with the subject. You'll have to experiment with angle and exposure to more accurately replicate this.

As for camera, any will do. Make sure that you aren't using a polarized filter as that could reduce the reflection.  Shoot at a longer focal length (100mm or more) to make the distant crowd look larger in the reflection.  Knowing this, you can also experiment with different focal lengths to see what you like the best.

Comment: Do I need any special camera or any DSLR will work?

Comment: Any dslr works. This photo specifically was shot on a longer lens, maybe 100-200mm. This compresses the background, making the crowd look closer to the subject. I'll update my post with that information.

Comment: Polarizing filters can be used to enhance, as well as reduce, reflections.  You should use one in this type of shot to adjust the reflection to the desired amount.